# Create Date display from existing data in JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have created an controller that creates some days ahead

```
$http.get('js/data.json')
    .success(function(data) {
      $scope.events = data.events;
      $scope.nextDates = [];
          for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
            // Locked the start date for this example
            var d = new Date('2016.04.24 23:14:13'); 
            $scope.nextDates.push(d.setDate(d.getDate() + i));
          }
     });
```

I then have a JSON file that contains some planned events

```
{
  "events": [
              { "name": "Monday Bloody Monday",
                "dates": ["Mon Apr 25 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)"]
              },
              { "name": "Hard Work",
                "dates": ["Mon Apr 25 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
                          "Tue Apr 26 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
                          "Wed Apr 27 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
                          "Thu Apr 28 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
                          "Fri Apr 29 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)"
                         ]
              }
             ]  
}
```

(Not sure if strings are the best way to store dates.. think that perphaps unix epo number will be better)

I tried the following without luck

```
<div ng-repeat="day in nextdates">
  <h2>{{day | amDateFormat:'dddd, Do MMMM YYYY'}}</h2>

  <div ng-repeat="event in events">
    <div ng-repeat="date in event.dates"
         ng-show="{ day.diff(Date(date)) < 0 }">
      <p>{{event.name}}</p>    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

BTW: I injected angular-moment (the `amDateFormat`) to help humans to read the output

**How do I compare the dates to see that it's the same day and then display it?**

---

The output should be like this

### **Monday, 25. april 2016**

Monday Bloody Monday

Hard Work

### **Tuesday, 26. april 2016**

Hard Work

### **Wednesday, 27. april 2016**

Hard Work

### **Thursday, 28. april 2016**

Hard Work

### **Friday, 29. april 2016**

Hard Work

Perhaps I should keep the logic in the controller...

Comment: What is your back end langue `C#` or else ?

Comment: javascript. Angular is the framework

Comment: are you using `Underscore.js` ?

Answer (score 1):

Hope you're using [**Underscore.js**](http://underscorejs.org/) where it's very natural selection of api when we are doing js development.Hope this will help to you.

***JS***

```
$scope.filteredEvents=[];

  _.each(nextdates, function (d) {
   _.each(events, function (e) {
   _.each(e.dates, function (dt) {
        var difference = moment(d) - moment(dt);
        if (difference == 0) {
           $scope.filteredEvents.push(e);
        } 
     });
   });
  });
```

***Html***

```
<div ng-repeat="day in nextdates">
  <h2>{{day | amDateFormat:'dddd, Do MMMM YYYY'}}</h2>

  <div ng-repeat="event in filteredEvents">
     <p>{{event.name}}</p>    
  </div>
</div>
```